# java spring azure cloud ad from cookie based to token based

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-azure

I have a spring boot azure active directory application and i need to change it from cookie based JSESSIONID to token based because currently its cookie based. The app is simple just a yaml file with client id,secret and tenant id and a hello world controller

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: native

spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: ${TENANTID}
        credential:
          client-id: ${CLIENTID}
          client-secret: ${CLIENTSECRET}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("Hello")
class WelcomeController {

    @GetMapping
    fun welcomeMessage(auth: Authentication): String {
        return "hELLO"
    }
}
```

I am pretty weak in what happens beetwen the scenes
Thanks